# net_ratelimit message in kernel log when creating multiple TCP connection in NONBLOCKING mode

Tags: c, sockets, networking, linux-kernel, tcp

I've a C program which tries to poll for devices in network and if the devices are available it tries read value from them. But when no devices are present running of the application creates following message in kernel log. Also there is no other warning/alert messages in the log than the below message. (Even after disabling ratelimit using `net.core.message_cost=0`)

```
net_ratelimit: xx callbacks supressed
```

And at the same time another application which broadcasts messages over network starts to fail in the send system call returning `EINVAL`. Once I stop the polling `TCP` client the `UDP Broadcast` application runs fine.

The system where I run this is a `RAMFS` based system running **3.14 series kernel** with `RT_PREEMPT` **patch applied**. I've written a sample application for which mimics same behavior as my original application when I start 5 process in background. (note that its more than 4 process which triggers it). Below is sample client code.

```
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <sys/socket.h>
#include <sys/select.h>
#include <sys/time.h>
#include <sys/ioctl.h>
#include <arpa/inet.h>
#include <netinet/in.h>

#include <unistd.h>
#include <errno.h>

#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

#define CHK_NULL(x) if ((x)==NULL) exit (1)
#define CHK_ERR(err,s) if ((err)==-1) { perror(s); exit(1); }
#define CHK_SSL(err) if ((err)==-1) { ERR_print_errors_fp(stderr); exit(2); }

int sfd;

void openProtocol(const char *hostname) {
     int sfd = socket(PF_INET, SOCK_STREAM, 0);
     CHK_ERR(sfd, "socket");

     struct sockaddr_in address;
     memset(&address, 0, sizeof(address));
     address.sin_family = PF_INET;
     address.sin_addr.s_addr = inet_addr(hostname);
     address.sin_port = htons(502);

     int opt = 1;
     int result = ioctl(sfd, FIONBIO, &opt);
     if (result == -1) {
      close(sfd);
      CHK_ERR(result, "ioctl");
     }

     result = connect(sfd, (struct sockaddr*)&address, sizeof(address));
     if (result == -1 && errno != EINPROGRESS) {
      close(sfd);
      CHK_ERR(result, "connect");
     }

     fd_set fdlist;
     FD_ZERO(&fdlist);
     struct timeval tm;
     tm.tv_sec = 1;
     tm.tv_usec = 0;

     result = select(sfd + 1, NULL, &fdlist, NULL, &tm);
     if (result == 0) {
      printf ("TCP/IP connection error!\n");
      close(sfd);
     }

     if (result == -1) {
      close(sfd);
      CHK_ERR(result, "select");
     }
}

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
     char *base_addr = "192.168.1.";
     unsigned short startAddr = 21;

     if ( argc < 3) {
      fprintf (stderr, "Please provide number of IP and wait period\n");
      exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
     }

     unsigned int no_of_ip;
     if (sscanf (argv[1], "%u", (unsigned int*)&no_of_ip) != 1 ) {
      fprintf (stderr, "Scan of number of device failed\n");
      exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
     }

     unsigned int wait_period;
     if (sscanf (argv[2], "%u", (unsigned int*)&wait_period) != 1) {
      fprintf (stderr, "Scan of wait period failed\n");
      exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
     }

     char full_addr[100];
     char last_part[10];
     while (1) {
      for (int i = startAddr; i < (startAddr + no_of_ip); i++) {
           memset(&full_addr[0], 0, sizeof(full_addr));
           memset(&last_part[0], 0, sizeof(last_part));
           strncat (full_addr, base_addr, sizeof(full_addr));
           snprintf (last_part, sizeof(last_part), "%u", i);
           strncat (full_addr, last_part, sizeof(full_addr));

           openProtocol(full_addr);
           usleep(wait_period * 1000);
      }   
     }

     return 0;
}
```

Application takes input as number of devices and wait time. I run 5 instances of above application via a shell script with **`128` as device number** and `5` as wait time (**5 ms**).

Now my question.

1. Why am I getting the `net_ratelimit` messages when running this application (**`5` instances**). I tried disabling `net_ratelimit` by setting `net.core.message_cost` to `0` but I can't find anything in the kernel log other than the `net_ratelimit` messages.
2. Why is an unrelated application (`UDP broadcast` client) is getting `EINVAL` when trying to send the broadcast. Also this happens only when my polling application runs. Killing polling application the broadcast client returns to normal.

PS: I could not get a better title line, if some one has better title line please suggest/edit ;-).

Comment: You are aware that the *net_ratelimit* messages are simply an indication that something in the kernel or drivers is flooding the message log? And not necessarily related to what happens on the interface?

Comment: @tofro yes I'm aware, but question is what is flooding the message log?.. I don't see anything other than net_ratelimit messages. I even tried doing this `echo 7 > /proc/sys/kernel/printk` but nothing is coming to log.

Comment: Next I would try then is making your `net.core.message_cost`change permanent through `/etc/sysctl` and re-boot as I have seen hints the dynamic update through the proc fs might not always work.

Comment: @tofro OK I've not tried making the change permanent I will try that and update my observations

Comment: So I made the changes as mentioned by @tofro but nothing comes in the kernel logs now. Obviously net_ratelimit messages stopped but I don't see anything else in the log. OTOH the broadcast client keeps getting EINVAL on trying to do the send

Comment: Nice but doesn't get you anywhere. I was hoping to see some message. Apparently trying top open up a number of TCP connections unsuccessfully seems to hog the network card.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/120495/discussion-between-copyninja-and-tofro).

Comment: @tofro is it possible to find if some how I'm hogging the network card?.. Also I've modified the broadcast client in question to use different interface card than the interface card on which the TCP polling application is running, still broadcast client gets EINVAL...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After upgrading the kernel to 4.1 series I could see the reason for the message. The actual root cause was below message

```
neighbour: arp_cache: neighbour table overflow
```

Then I noticed that I'm adding entries into ARP cache which crossed 1024 which is default limit. After fixing this the issue of callback supressed messages stopped. I guess that was a bug in 3.14 series which did not provide the actual cause of `call  back supressed` messages.